# Why do threads have their stack persist when terminated & not detached?

Tags: c++, multithreading

When you're using threads, and a thread runs to termination, but was not detached, it is in a zombie state, waiting to be reaped with a join or to be detached so that its resources can be cleaned up.

I read that two of the 'resources' that are not cleaned up when a thread is a zombie are the stack and the return value.

Can someone tell me the logic for allowing the stack to persist until a join is made?  If there is a separate location for the return value I cannot think of a good reason - but I'm sure there is one and I'd like to know it for when I use threads.

Comment: I'd guess this is a very OS dependent question. Also, how can you tell the stack memory is not being released?

Comment: Maybe the return value is stored on the stack? But in general this will be extremely system dependent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The technical implementation of keeping the stack alive is easier. Your threads implementation can use the bottom of the stack as working space even for unregistering the current thread from the scheduler. Afterwards, the context of the thread calling `join()` can be used to delete the space.

If you would delete the stack before `join()` - that is, in the context of the terminating thread - you would have no stack or other memory for the short time between the stack deletion and the thread unregistering.

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not the stack is reclaimed as soon as the thread exits depends on the OS.

The following thread is a good read: [link](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.programming.threads/browse_thread/thread/ced04acf41c04a7c?pli=1).

I find the following post by Roger Faulkner quite interesting:

> At least in Solaris 9 and 10, thread stacks that are allocated by 
>   the 
>   library (using mmap()) are freed for reuse immediately upon thread 
>   termination.  The thread structure, containing the thread-id and the 
>   return value, is not freed until pthread_join() (or pthread_detach()).
>
> A cache of up to 10 thread stacks is kept for rapid reuse for new 
>   threads.  Older stacks beyond the cache limit are munmap()d.

On my Ubuntu system, the stack isn't reclaimed until `pthread_join()` is called. I suspect this is simply an artefact of the implementation rather than a conscious design decision.